# ionic 2 splash screen hiding, but not image?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have stopped splash screen loading initially using **this.splashscreen.hide()** and it worked. But still splash image used for splash screen is loading. How can I stop that one? Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: just delete that splash image from resource folder, might be work?

Comment: Is your splashscreen image in the resources folder?

Comment: By removing splash image in resources folder also causing same issue @RohanJMohite

Comment: yes it is in resources folder only @KevinRED

Comment: `this.splashscreen.hide()` will work when the app is ready actually. So anyway you will see it for the first time. Since you want it to get stopped, Add the below lines in to your `config.xml` file. `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />`               Let me know if it works.

Comment: it is not working again it may opening splash screen initially @KevinRED

Comment: I didn't get you, can you please explain. Thank you

Comment: i want to load my slides screen initially in my app for that i have used ```this.splashscreen.hide()``` when platform is ready. splashscreen is getting hide but splash image used for loading splash screen is loading initially exactly this is my issue?
for that i have removed
-> splash images in resources folder

but removing those images also didn't work

and again i have tried with the solution you gave to put in ```config.xml```
but it may also not working.

@KevinRED